# Как реализовать передвижение по полю в pygame кнопками WASD?

Tags: python, pygame

Не понимаю как реализовать движение по полю в python библиотеки pygame кнопками wasd

```
import pygame
import funcs

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('hello')

background = pygame.image.load('img/background.png')
person = pygame.image.load('img/person.png')

display_w = 500
display_h = 500

loc_x = 100
loc_y = 100

game_exit = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h))
game_display.blit(background, (0, 0))
game_display.blit(person, (loc_x, loc_y))


class Inventory:
    key = False


def process_keyboard(event):
    global loc_x, loc_y
    if event.type == pygame.event.get:
        if event.key == pygame.KeyW:
            loc_y += 25
        if event.type == pygame.KeyS:
            loc_y -= 25
        if event.type == pygame.KeyA:
            loc_x -= 25
        if event.type == pygame.KeyD:
            loc_x += 25


def game_loop(update_time):
    global game_exit
    while not game_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)

            process_keyboard(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
                quit()


pygame.display.update()

game_loop(30)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: После цикла обработки событий может вызвать опять game_display.blit(person, (loc_x, loc_y))? Потому что изменение координат надо как-то отобразить. Ну то есть внутри while после цикла for.

Comment: @CrazyElf, там всё надо переделывать

Comment: Это тоже надо, но не только

Answer (score 1):

Ниже указан код, который должен быть:

```
import pygame
import funcs

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('hello')

background = pygame.image.load('img/background.png')
person = pygame.image.load('img/person.png')

display_w = 500
display_h = 500

loc_x = 100
loc_y = 100

game_exit = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h))
game_display.blit(background, (0, 0))
game_display.blit(person, (loc_x, loc_y))

class Inventory:
    key = False

def game_loop(update_time):
    global game_exit
    while not game_exit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    loc_y += 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    loc_y -= 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    loc_x -= 25
                if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    loc_x += 25
    game_display.blit(background, (0, 0))
    game_display.blit(person, (loc_x, loc_y))

game_loop(30)
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции process_keyboard заместо

```
if event.type == pygame.event.get:
```

сделай

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

Но это будет только по нажатию работать одиночно, если хочешь чтобы нажал на клавишу и событие выполнялось пока ты не отпустишь, то тебе надо сделать примерно так

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        key_w = True # например пусть будет клавиша w
elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_w:
        key_w = False
```

Теперь при удержании клавиши w переменная key_w будет True